# Работа с WiFi на C#

Tags: c#, wifi

День добрый! Суть моего вопроса заключается в следующем: возможно ли, используя C#, работать с WiFi, то есть получать список доступных сетей, их параметры (уровень сигнала и т.п.), а так же блокировать возможность подключения к определённым из них. И если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На просторах Nuget'ов обнаружил библиотеку [SimpleWiFi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleWifi/). Включает в себя все необходимое, проста в обращении. Так же находится [в открытом доступе на GitHub](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi) (как и [пример использования](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi/tree/example))

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотека [NativeWifi](http://www.outme.ru/assets/images/resize/public/progs/NativeWifi.zip)
Добавляем ее в references, прописываем

```
using NativeWifi;
```

Список сетей:

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList( 0 );
```

И т.д. подробнее [тут](http://www.outme.ru/poisk-setej-i-podklyuchenie-k-wi-fi-na-c.html).
А вот блокировку уже сложнее сделать, из приложения, допустим, можно без проблем сделать, а вот на уровне системы - уже задача нетривиальная.

Comment: Уже натыкался на эти 2 класса (что трудно назвать библиотекой). Они ни чуть не облегчают работы с WiFi, ибо автор руководствовался какой-то странной логикой при написании кода, так что особой структурностью он не обладает. Так что я и был в поисках чего-то более совершенного